# List Combinations c#

Tags: c#, .net, combinations

I have a 4 collections.

```
{ A1, A2, A3, ...}
{ B1, B1, B3, ...}
{ C1, C2, C3, ...}
{ D1, D2, D3, ...}
```

I need to find all of the possible combinations using the following rules:

1. 1 item from the first and fourth collections
2. 2 items from the second collection
3. 3 items from the third

**Example combinations:**

```
{A1, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, D1}
{A2, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, D1}
```

Comment: This question is too broad and poorly explained.  Please post what you have attempted so far.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to idea how to tackle this.  I figure that a collection of for<> loops could give me the combinations, bit I am not certain.

Comment: Do you need the number of possible combinations?  Or what?  How do you expect the output to be formatted?  You need to provide more information.

Comment: @Who cares, have you designed the logic for this?

Comment: I can draw what I need. But I can't figure out how to implement it.

Comment: Please explain your logic here and then explain what have you tried in the code.

Comment: One thing of note, based on what you've provided this would produce a list of over 2 billion (permutation) or 180 million (combinations) based on what you've provided. Is that what you're actually wanting?

Comment: Actually, my complete lists come up to 380 Billion combinations. And, yes, that is what I need. The ones above are samples.

Comment: Why do you need to generate so many of these? I'm sensing XY problem here

Comment: Thanks @Emmanuel.  That edit makes more sense

Comment: We need to make sure that we process 100% of the combinations.  Some coworkers attempted this, but in the end non of them has been able to provide 100% coverage. We are not mathematicians, so have not been able to come up with valid logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio was taking too long to load, so I did it in JavaScript since I could test in my console.  This will print out all the choices.  (Also it sounds more like a "what's the algorithm for this?" not "what's the algorithm for this *in C#*?")

```
function makeGroup(id, count) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= count; i++) {
    result.push(id + i);
  }
  return result;
}

function choose(group, count) {
  if (count === 1) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
      result.push([group[i]]);
    }
    return result;
  }
  if (count === 2) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < group.length; j++) {
        if (i !== j && 
            i < j) {
          result.push([group[i], group[j]]);
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
  if (count === 3) {
    var result = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
      for (var j = 0; j < group.length; j++) {
        for (var k = 0; k < group.length; k++) {
          if (i !== j && i !== k && j !== k &&
              i < j && j < k) {
            result.push([group[i], group[j], group[k]]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
}

var groupA = makeGroup('A', 2);
var groupB = makeGroup('B', 2);
var groupC = makeGroup('C', 3);
var groupD = makeGroup('D', 1);

choose(groupA, 1).forEach(function (a) { 
  choose(groupB, 2).forEach(function (b) {
    choose(groupC, 3).forEach(function (c) {
      choose(groupD, 1).forEach(function (d) {
        console.log(a + " " + b[0] + " " + b[1] + " " + c[0] + " " + c[1] + " " + c[2] + " " + d[0]);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Example output:

```
A1 B1 B2 C1 C2 C3 D1
A2 B1 B2 C1 C2 C3 D1
```

---

To see an example of it working, you can do:

```
var testGroup = makeGroup('T', 4);

var choose1 = choose(testGroup, 1);
var choose2 = choose(testGroup, 2);
var choose3 = choose(testGroup, 3);

console.log(JSON.stringify(choose1));
console.log(JSON.stringify(choose2));
console.log(JSON.stringify(choose3));
```

And see that it chooses correctly:

```
[["T1"],["T2"],["T3"],["T4"]]
[["T1","T2"],["T1","T3"],["T1","T4"],["T2","T3"],["T2","T4"],["T3","T4"]]
[["T1","T2","T3"],["T1","T2","T4"],["T1","T3","T4"],["T2","T3","T4"]]
```

Answer (score 2):

I've created this code to do what you want:

```
var aa = new[] { "A1", "A2", "A3", "A4" };
var bb = new[] { "B1", "B2", "B3", "B4" };
var cc = new[] { "C1", "C2", "C3", "C4" };
var dd = new[] { "D1", "D2", "D3", "D4" };

var query =
    from a in aa.SelectMembers()
    from b1 in bb.SelectMembers()
    from b2 in b1.Remainder.SelectMembers()
    from c1 in cc.SelectMembers()
    from c2 in c1.Remainder.SelectMembers()
    from c3 in c2.Remainder.SelectMembers()
    from d in aa.SelectMembers()
    select new []
    {
        a.Selected, b1.Selected, b2.Selected, c1.Selected,
        c2.Selected, c3.Selected, d.Selected,
    };
```

It produces, for my example, 4,608 combinations.

```
A1, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, A1 
A1, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, A2 
A1, B1, B2, C1, C2, C3, A3 
...
A4, B4, B3, C4, C3, C2, A3 
A4, B4, B3, C4, C3, C2, A4
```

The two supporting bits of code you need are:

```
public static class Ex
{
    public static IEnumerable<Member<T>> SelectMembers<T>(this IEnumerable<T> @this)
    {
        if (@this == null || !@this.Any())
        {
            yield break;
        }
        else
        {
            for (var i = 0; i < @this.Count(); i++)
            {
                yield return new Member<T>(@this.Skip(i).First(), @this.Take(i).Concat(@this.Skip(i + 1)));
            }
        }
    }
}

public sealed class Member<T>
{ 
    private readonly T _Selected; 
    private readonly IEnumerable<T> _Remainder; 

    public T Selected { get { return _Selected; } } 
    public IEnumerable<T> Remainder { get { return _Remainder; } } 

    public Member(T Selected, IEnumerable<T> Remainder) 
    { 
        _Selected = Selected; 
        _Remainder = Remainder;    
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        string[] A = { "a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5" };
        string[] B = { "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "b5", "b6", "b7", "b8", "b9", "b10"};
        string[] C = { "c1", "c2", "c3", "c4", "c5", "c6", "c7", "c8", "c9", "c10", "c11", "c12", "c13", "c14", "c15"};
        string[] D = { "d1", "d2", "d3", "d4", "d5"};
        for(int i=0; i<A.Length;i++)
        {
            Console.Write(A[i]);
            for (int j = i * 2; j < i*2 +2; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(B[j]);                    
            }
            for (int k = i * 3; k < i*3+3; k++)
            {
                Console.Write(C[k]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(D[i]);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

Output will be like this:

a1b1b2c1c2c3d1
a2b3b4c4c5c6d2
.....